# Passing String Value From Map View to Detail View

Tags: xcode, variables, nsstring, android-mapview

I am attempting to pass a string variable from a Map View Controller to a Detail View Controller after the click of a callout button. I took the title of the callout button and stored it in an NSString object (which had been synthesized in the Map View Controller).

I then allocated and initialized the Map View Controller in the Detail View Controller and attempted to log the value once in the new view controller and it returned as null. Here's the code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    TheLocations *annotationTapped = (TheLocations *)view.annotation;

    NSLog(@"button clicked on annotaion %@", annotationTapped);

    MapViewController *thisMap = (MapViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    dvc.title = view.annotation.title;
    pinTitle = dvc.title;
    NSLog(@"%@", pinTitle);

    [thisMap switchViews:self.view toView:dvc.view];
}
```

This results in a successful log of "pinTitle"'s value. pinTitle has been created and synthesized, so it's a string of this Map View.

Now, I switch over to the Detail View and entered this code into the viewDidLoad method:

```
MapViewController *mvc = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", mvc.pinTitle);
```

It recognizes "pinTitle" and allows it to log out but returns "(null)" so somewhere along the way the value of pinTitle was lost. How do I get pinTitle to retain it's value when I switch views? Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the detail view's `viewDidLoad` method, you are creating a new instance of `MapViewController` which is separate from the instance being referenced in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`.

In that new, separate instance, `pinTitle` is not set and has a default value of null.

I'm not sure why you need the `pinTitle` variable in any case.

In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, you are setting `dvc.title` so in the `viewDidLoad` of the `DetailViewController`, you would access that value using `self.title`.  You don't need to reference `MapViewController`.

Comment: I think what you meant to do (or really want to do) is add pinTitle as a property in DetailViewController (not MapViewController).  This would be better than using title since the built-in title property of a UIViewController is used as the heading for the navigation toolbar.

Comment: Oh wow, ok. Much easier than I thought. I keep making things way more convoluted than they need to be. Thanks, you've been a huge help with my Map Kit.

Comment: While you can set the title and carry it over, is there a way to do multiple variables (like 'subtitle' as well). I didn't want to get into setting up a whole "pinTitle"-like variable if there's an easier way to do more than one 'title' on a Map View page.

Comment: If you want to pass multiple fields to the detail view, you either have to create a separate property for each one or just define the whole annotation object as a single property and pass that so the detail view will have access to all the fields in the annotation.  It's also possible to create a custom init method for the detail view controller so you can pass the field(s) right when you alloc+init it.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. So what I did was I created an NSString called "addressString" and then was able to set 'dvc.addressString = view.annotation.subtitle" and that did the trick. I guess I could do that for as many variables as I want!